Could web rtc server see my real ip address?
I connect the virtual classroom via browser which uses Adobe connect infrastructure. But I also use browser add on called "Veepn" which I think works more like a proxy server. When I check out this site : https://browserleaks.com/webrtc it shows my real IP, even the VPN is on, strangely..
When the class started I typed the browser://webrtc-internals/ command and get this output right away: webrtc internals output As you can see there is no Stun server as the iceServers shows "[]".
and also I get the dump data from browser here : https://codeshare.io/xLgnND
So my questions are:

What is the p2p method here? Adobe's proprietary RTMPS or WebRTC?
If it is WebRTC, than how the connection is being made without a Stun server? Or without knowing the IP address how the connection established?
Is my IP adress exposed according to the picture above, even I use a proxy server?

Thanks in advance!
I use browser based VPN to conceal my IP adress. But I don't know I achieved my goals.

posting on reddit and here at the same time is rather unhelpful: https://www.reddit.com/r/WebRTC/comments/1ckwxry/is_my_ip_being_exposed/
